# How do I vectorize this calculation in numpy

Tags: numpy, vectorization

How do I vectorize the following calculation if a and b are appropriately sized numpy arrays?

```
total = a[0]
for ix in range(1, len(a)):
   total = total*b[ix-1] + a[ix]
```

Comment: Normally calculations of the type `a[i] = f(a[i-1])` are not vectorizable unless you get lucky and can do a [`ufunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) trick.   I don't see a way to do that here.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, there is a `ufunc` trick that works if you do some algebra.  In this case the `ufunc` is `multiply` and the trick is `accumulate`.

```
c = np.r_[np.multiply.accumulate(b[0:-1][::-1])[::-1], 1]
total2 = np.sum(a * c)
```

What this does: Algebraically, you are summing `a[i]` times the product of `b[i:]` over `for i in range(a.size)`.  To do this, flip `b` and get the running product of all but the last number (assuming `a` and `b` are the same length) and then flip it back.  The last value should be 1 because the final `a` value is just added.

**Testing**

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, 40)
b = 1 + np.random.rand(40)

total = a[0]
for ix in range(1, len(a)):
   total = total*b[ix-1] + a[ix]

total
278443993.10494208

total2
278443993.10494208
```

Comment: The following variation of @DanielF's excellent answer improves speed by >= 2x: `np.sum(np.cumprod(b[-2::-1])[::-1] * a[:-1]) + a[-1]`